# Allow Clicking through element but still register hover

Tags: html, css, events, dom, click

Heres my problem: I have an `a` tag that I am using as an arrow that you can hover over to change the scroll of a div.. That part works. However, I then want you to be able to click through to the other `a` elements in the div below this link. All of the other tutorials that show how to allow clicks to fall through also stop my Javascript from being able to register the mouse events on the topmost link.
Is there any way to fix this issue? [Here's a link to what I'm trying to do](http://mrfishie.com/products/playzone/index.php?p=my%20awesome%20game).
Try hovering over the list of items at the top of the screen. Two arrows will appear. Those are the links that I want to be visible to events but still be able to clicked through.
The code is pretty simple for those:

```
<a id="lefthover" href="javascript:void(0);">◄</a>
<a id="righthover" href="javascript:void(0);">►</a>
```

If you need any more links, here is a pretty basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gq3nK/). Pretty much, if you click on one of the arrows and the mouse is over an arrow and one of the boxes, it should show both alert boxes (so it triggers both).
Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @user1479606 There is a link to what I am trying to do. Take a look there. Also, I do not believe that the problem has anything to do with the code.

Comment: can you create a simpler example on jsfiddle. i dont know which part you are talking about on your website. i don't want to go through all the source code

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: I don't think it's possible while retaining their functionality. I would just reduce the width of the anchors.

Comment: @Jeemusu OK. I will try another way around this problem, because I still need the anchors (or at least the effects of the anchors) to be around that wide.

Comment: I think that pointer-events:none; should work in modern browsers.

Comment: Now I don't want to get too indepth with this but here something you could try that might work (or not). Make a div outside of your page that include the 2 anchor tags. Use Jscript and/or Jquery on your div used to place your anchor to trigger the anchor hover event on hovering that div. I don't know if it's gonna work or not. I know I used a onClick event on a button to call another onClick event on an hidden button. Which is why I believe on hover you can call another element hover (at least it would make sense). Good luck.

Comment: @snaplemouton That does not seem to work, however I have found that simply by modifying my code I can make the effects of the `a` tag wider than the actual tag, which does work.